# Read and write data via Serial Port to LOG screen using MultiThreading C#

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-controls, serial-port

I wrote a small application which has s UserControl called "SerialPortComm" that responsible to send and receive data via Serial Port, and print it on a LOG screen (RichTextBox).

But the problem is when I'm sending\receiving a data (strings) which need some delays between the commands, my MainWindow application that owns the "SerialPortComm" UserControl, freezes until all the IO operations ends.

I want to have the ability to see the data running on my LOG screen in real-time, and I understand that I need a Thread which responsible on that.

**How do I do that??**

Here are some partial relevant code from my application.

***UserControl "SerialPortComm" class .cs***

```
public partial class SerialPortComm : UserControl
{        
    private void open_port_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mySerialPort.PortName = ComNumber;
        mySerialPort.BaudRate = BaudRate;
        mySerialPort.Open();
        mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
     }


    private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int i = 0;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(80); // waiting for filling all the buffe
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            DataRX = sp.ReadExisting();

            Print_To_Log(DataRX, Brushes.Black);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }


    private void Print_To_Log(string data, SolidColorBrush color)
    {
        // Print it on the Log
        RichTextBox_logView.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
        {
            TextRange rangeOfTextInput = new TextRange(RichTextBox_logView.Document.ContentEnd, RichTextBox_logView.Document.ContentEnd);
            rangeOfTextInput.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, color);
            RichTextBox_logView.AppendText(data);
            RichTextBox_logView.ScrollToEnd();
        });
    }


    // Function that responsible to send the data to the serial port
    public static void SetStringDataFromControl(string content)
    {
        try
        {
            mySerialPort.Write(content + "\n");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I have another class which called "Commands" that responsible to send data to Serial Port class

***Commands.cs***

```
class Commands
{
    public void SetCommand(string command)
    {
        SerialPortComm.SetStringDataFromControl(command);
    }

    private bool SetMultipleCommands(string[] commandsArray, string expectedResult = "")
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < commandsArray.Length; i++)
        {
            SetCommand(commandsArray[i]);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        // Check if our expected result string is appears on the LOG
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(150);
        if (SerialPortComm.DataRX.Contains(expectedResult))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The expected result '" + expectedResult + "' was not found!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

***Class MainWindow.cs***

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Commands cmd = new Commands();

    cmd.SetCommand("display");
    cmd.SetMultipleCommands(new string[] { "modulator", "line" });
    // ....
}
```

Please Help!

Comment: Have you searched StackOverflow (or the web) for `serialport thread c#` or something similar? There are already quite a lot of questions and answers that might be worth to take a look at.

Comment: Yes, I have search for an answer but unfortunately I didn't find something that helped me, so that is why I ask a new question to my problem.

Comment: Please if someone know, I will glad to some help.

Comment: Serial ports are pretty slow.  But at ~1000 chars per second typically, still a wholeheckofalot faster than a human can ever read.  And when you never remove any text, eventually faster than the UI thread can keep up with.  So it just goes catatonic, trying to keep appending and scrolling megabytes worth of text and never being able to catch up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I've done the work using `Dispatcher`:
The `_threadStart` is just `ThreadStart` found in `System.Threading`.

```
_dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        _threadStart = delegate()
        {
            _dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<object>(trial), DispatcherPriority.Normal, new object[] {this});
        };
public void MultiThread()
    {
        _thread = new Thread(_threadStart) {Name = "MyApp - VM Worker"};
        _thread.Start();
    }

    void trial(object param)
    {
        this.Test = "Tested";
    }
```

HTH.